# How can I delete a python script from rasperry pi?

Tags: python

I recently have installed a script that didn't work properly, and now I want to remove it. The script allowed the pi to boot when pin 5 was connected to ground with a resistor, but it doesn't work and prevents the pi from booting. I managed to ssh into the console but im not sure what to do from here. I can access the file by typing python /home/pi/scripts/shutdown.py.

Comment: What script?  What instructions were you following?  **Please edit this information into your question.**

Answer (score 4):

Once you've sshed into the console, you can type `rm /home/pi/scripts/shutdown.py` to remove the file. Type `man rm` to learn about the `rm` command.

Comment: If you just want to prevent it from running and might like to try to change it, you can optionally just "move" the script to a different location so it won't execute via the `mv` command.  e.g. `mv <path/filename> <new-location or new-name>`